# How many times does a range of values contain the end of the month

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table that has 2 values.
Value a phone was activated and a value when phone was deactivated.
I want to find out how many times that phone was still active on the last day of any given month.

```
Table1
    phone1     DateActivated     DateDeactivated      HowManyTimesLastDayOfMonth
    123        3/1/2016          3/15/2016            0
    456        3/10/2016         6/25/2016            3
    789        5/25/2016         10/10/2016           5
```

Comment: Use `MONTHS_BETWEEN ` function: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions089.htm  This function calculates number of months between two dates, in your case: deactivation date and activation date.

Comment: In trying to get the valid number of months the phone was active on the last day of said month, you need to do MONTHS_BETWEEN(FIRST_DAY(DateDeactivated+1)).  This catches the edge case that the DateDeactivated was, in fact, the last day of the month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To amplify my comment:

```
SELECT phone1, DateActivated, DateDeactivated,
       MONTHS_BETWEEN(FIRST_DAY(DateActivated+1), FIRST_DAY(DateDeactivated+1)) HowManyTimesLastDay
  FROM mytable;
```

I should have explained better.  The reason you take first_day(DateActivated+1) is that the second date (going to the first day of the next month) needs to be sure that it's not a full month - so if the phone was activated on March 1 and deactivated on March 25th, it doesn't show a full month.  The reason for FIRST_DAY(DateDeactivated + 1) is to make sure that in the event that the deactivation occurred on the last day of a month that that counted towards the total.

Comment: You had it right the first time. Don't add 1 to DateActivated.

Comment: No because if it was activated on the first of the month and deactivated on the last day of the month, unless deactivation is inclusive of the deactivation date, it would erroneously report a month where it really wasn't active on the last day of the month.  If deactivation counts the last day of a month, the FIRST_DAY(DateActivated) addition can be removed.  I suppose this could be "CASE"d to determine with something simple.

Comment: You raise a valid question - should the DateDeactivated be included in the count, if it is a month-end date? If the answer is NO, then you shouldn't add 1 to EITHER term: if you do, the count for March 1 through March 31 will become 1 instead of 0.

Comment: Agreed.  So adding a case statement to the query based on <something> would fix this such that it could either add 0 (zero) or 1 (one) to either / or.

Comment: Think about it again. Assuming dateDeactivated should not be included, what problem do you see if you don't add 1 to either date, you just measure months_between the first_day of each, and don't do any adjustments with CASE expression? I believe you will get the correct answer in all cases.

Comment: I think MONTHS_BETWEEN('01-JAN-2017','31-JAN-2017') will yield "0" (zero) even though there is a full month involved.  Granted, this is an edge case.  But edge cases cause me the most debugging trouble.  edit:  I know, TO_DATE...

Comment: The question wasn't "how many full months" but how many "month-end dates" are included. If 31-JAN is not included, then there is no month-end date in that interval.

Comment: mathguy you are correct.  i don't need full months, only if that end of month day occurs.  a phone might only be active for 5 days or even 1 day, i just need to know how many times did end of month occur in a range.

Comment: I used this:

    MONTHS_BETWEEN(
trunc(NVL(DateDeActivated, TO_DATE('09-12-16', 'DD-MM-YY'))) - (to_number(to_char(NVL(DateDeActivated, TO_DATE('09-12-16', 'DD-MM-YY')),'DD')) - 1), 
trunc(NVL(DateActivated, TO_DATE('09-12-16', 'DD-MM-YY'))) - (to_number(to_char(NVL(DateActivated, TO_DATE('09-12-16', 'DD-MM-YY')),'DD')) - 1)) AS Test1,